# Loading Java class from bytes using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classloader

I'm trying to load java class from bytes using JNI.

This java class

```java
package plus.launch;

public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Test defined!");
    }
}
```

In C++ I call this and get an error

```cpp
jclass DefClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name, jobject loader, const jbyte *buf, jsize bufLen){
//                   "plus.launch.Test" ^^
    return (*env)->DefineClass(env, name, loader, buf, bufLen);
}
```

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: plus/launch/Test (wrong name:
> plus.launch.Test)

How to fix it?

And I get a strange error (I also tried putting the class name `Test`, `plus/launch/Test.class` and still get a similar error).

Comment: You ClassLoader needs to know where to find that class. In your case, you should write a custom classloader, which grabs the bytes and loads them as a class.

Comment: According to the documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#DefineClass this method defines a class from an array of bytes. I also tried to pass an empty or corrupted array, as expected - there was a class format error

Comment: The JVM uses slashes to separate packages and class names, not dots. Pass `plus/launch/Test` as name instead.

Comment: it worked, thanks

Comment: You don’t need JNI for this.

Comment: I know that there is a ClassLoader#defineClass, but it did not suit me for a number of reasons

Comment: Such as? The pain of engaging in JNI would outweigh them all to me, whatever they were, and I’ve written a lot of JNI.